# Adding Body Text to iCalendar File using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, icalendar

I've been successful in creating an ics file, which will add my event to Outlook and Google calendars.  Here's my output, once JS has done its magic:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Company Name//Events Finder//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20140218T090000
UID:1392737374677_487546@mysite.com
DTSTART:20140218T090000
DTEND:20140218T100000
LOCATION:New Orleans
SUMMARY:The Name of My Event
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

However, I've been unable to find the datatype that will add text to the body of the Google/Outlook event.  Summary adds the title, but beyond that, I'm at a loss.

[image: Example of region I'd like to add text to]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DESCRIPTION property is what you are looking for. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.1.5